# Recommendations for batch renaming files based on a spreadsheet in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, file-rename

Our office recently moved from one research project management system to another. We received back a whole bunch of data tables with crosswalks for individual study documents. Net result is several thousand folders, each of which contains one to hundreds of documents, all with a very generic name (such as Document_1234). We have a data table spreadsheet that tells us what each file was originally named (e.g. Document_1234 = Study Protocol 2020-05-01). Using the crosswalk is incredibly painful. What I'd like to do is go through these folders, check each file name, and if there is a match for that file name in the spreadsheet (for sake of example call it column 1), replace it with the corresponding original file name (from column 2). While files are numbered sequentially, they are unique - all files across all folders are listed in the same crosswalk spreadsheet, so I'd have to walk through every line of the spreadsheet for each individual folder containing files that need to be renamed. Data are on a secure network share drive.

Have access to PowerShell but that's it (locked down corporate environment, no other scripting languages installed.)

Script is MOSTLY working but there are a few errors I can't figure out.

Specifically:

1. Name collisions - script works fine on small test directory, but is not auto-incrementing filenames on larger copy of the full dataset. I either see a file exists error, or no error at all.
2. Errors - the Try/Catch block is not actually capturing all errors. If I get it to capture name collisions, it misses illegal file names, and vice versa. My attempt to push errors into a separate hash for follow-up is not working consistently.
3. Completion - Attempting to run this on my test copy of the data results in a very large number of files that are not renamed. No errors to explain why. Manually searching the dataset for specific files that were not renamed shows that the key/value pair exists in the set, but I cannot figure out whether this is an error with the code or the data. Any suggestions would help.

```
# path to target folder
$path = $args[0];
# csv file listing CURRENT filename, NEW filename
# source file lists 'filename.ext, newfilename' (no extension)
$source = $args[1];
# hash to store current/new names
$hash = @{}
# hash to store errors
$errorhash = @{};
# import the csv file and loop through each line to populate hash
foreach ($item in (Import-Csv -Path $source)) {
    $hash[$item.CURRENT] = $item.NEW
    }
# look in the $path directory for files with these names
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Recurse)) {
    # does the directory have a matching file?
    if ($hash.ContainsKey($file.Name)) {
        Try {
            # check whether we can just rename the file. can we?
            # counter
            $num = 1;
            # variables for new name, file path, extension, and new name including path
            $newname = $hash[$file.Name];
            $filepath = Split-Path -Path $file.FullName;
            $ext = $file.Extension;
            # i need to check whether the renamed file already exists
            # feels unnecessary to use 2 lines, but does not seem to work if combined in one line
            $newfull = $newname+$ext;
            $foo = Join-Path -Path $filepath -ChildPath $newfull;
            # check if the file exists, and if so, increment file name by appending counter
            while(Test-Path -Path $foo) {
                # filename collision errors here are not caught in the Try: never gets pushed to the hash?
                $newname = $hash[$file.Name] + "_$num";
                $newfull = $newname+$ext;
                $foo = Join-Path -Path $filepath -ChildPath $newfull;
                $num+=1;
                }
            # now that we have verified the filename doesn't already exist, rename the file
            $file | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}{1}' -f $newname, $ext) -ErrorAction Continue
            }
        Catch {
            # error check: take the offending file name and add it to a new hash of errors
            $k = $file.FullName;
            $errorhash.Add($k, $hash[$file.Name]);
            }
        }
    }
# before we stop, write the hash of errors to a file
$errorhash.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object -Property Key,Value | Export-Csv -Path error.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The recommendation would be to export the spreadsheet to a CSV file so you can easily use `Import-Csv` within PowerShell to access the data in it. With that said, what does your code look like so far? (Of necessity, this site is not a free script writing service.)

Comment: Import-Excel works without conversion. Key to me here was "get rid of the extraneous columns" - I'm usually working too hard to exclude them and find the columns I want, when it's easier to just delete them.

Comment: Import-Excel is not something that comes with PowerShell; it must be an external or third-party module.

Comment: It was introduced in a Microsoft scripting blog - so if not Microsoft-created, it's at least endorsed. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a question abbout bulk renaming files with a generic name, do the following:

From the Excel, save (at least the two important columns) as CSV file

This file may then look something like this (from your question I gather only the BaseNames are listed):

```
"genericname","originalname"
"Document_1234","Study Protocol 2020-05-01"
"Document_1235","Working Protocol 2020-05-21"
```

Next, in PowerShell import that CSV and create a lookup Hashtable from it where each Key is from the 'genericname' column and each corresponding Value is from the 'originalname' column

```
# create a lookup Hashtable
$lookup = @{}
# import the CSV file and loop through to build up the $lookup hash
foreach ($item in (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\filenames.csv')) {
    $lookup[$item.genericname] = $item.originalname
}
```

Now, get the files and test if their BaseName can be found as one of the hash Keys

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\Path\To\The\RootFolder' -File -Recurse)) {
    # if the lookup hash has a Key for the file's BaseName
    if ($lookup.ContainsKey($file.BaseName)) {
        # rename the file with the value stored in the Hashtable
        $file | Rename-Item -NewName ('{0}{1}' -f $lookup[$file.BaseName], $file.Extension)
    }
}
```

Comment: Several of my lists include files with same base name but different extensions - not necessarily corresponding to the same "old" name. As such using a list that includes extension in current name - thus using `$file.Name` instead of `$file.BaseName`.